# Gödel but Noether?

Tags: umlaut, person-names

Kurt Gödel and Emmy Noether are both prominent mathematicians.
And I’m wondering why so many people write Gödel with umlaut but not Nöther.
I’ve searched and found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Noether's_theorem) asserting that

> Only Noether is correct. She never used an umlaut in her own name, as Goethe never used an umlaut in his.

But then, why do we write Gödel?
Is it just conventional or is there any reason I don’t know?
Moreover, what do you think is more appropriate, writing with umlaut or with *e* following after the vowel?
I’ve seen somewhere that omitting umlaut can be offensive in some countries, but I’m not sure if that was German. 
But the same link has also this paragraph:

> … the umlaut in German has long been considered an abbreviated form for the same vowel followed by the latter *e*.

So does that mean rather omitting the umlaut and attaching the additional *e* is more formal?
I’ve learned German before and I was taught that attaching *e* is only allowed when your keyboard does not support umlauts.
I’m totally confused.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25550/use-of-ss-or-%C3%9F-in-a-surname

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you learnt is correct. You always write the umlaut unless you don’t have it on  your keyboard. However especially in names the rules are somewhat flexible. So you might see people using the e behind the vowel instead of the umlaut and if that’s how the name is spelled then the official rule does not apply anymore. This is based on a case by case decision, so the famous Goethe is always spelled with oe however your neighbour might have the last name Göthe. If you want to refer to him you should use the ö, unless the system you use doesn’t allow it.
There is no other way than memorizing these names.

And it’s also true that you should not omit either the two dots or the e. I cannot think of any insulting difference (although I think I read that there are some) but it can change the meaning of a word completely. 
E.g. *nah —  close* vs. *näh — sew.*

Comment: o_O So that means Gödel is Gödel and Noether is Noether... I have one more question; does 'oe' pronounce different from 'ö' in this case?

Comment: Yes, it's just how it is. And no. The pronunciation is exactly the same. These are just two ways to write the same letter

Comment: Thanks for your explanation; I'll just wait a bit more to see other possible answers and then accept your answer.

Comment: Nowadays the umlauted letters are different letters. Replacing *ü* by *u* is no more acceptable than replacing it by *y*, say. However, the umlauts historically developed out of *ue* because medieval scribes wrote the *e* in a tiny form above the *u*, and the tiny *e* became two dots. This is why there is an unbroken tradition to replace *ü* by *ue* whenever no *ü* is available. But since *ü* is a first-class letter nowadays, it may also be used for the sound in words that were never written with *ue*, and freely replacing actual *ue* by *ü* is not acceptable.

Comment: Whereas the spellings of names were once completely free and e.g. *Goethe* is only one of several variants used by a certain 18th/19th century German poet (he also used *Göthe* and *Göte*), it is now fixed up to the letter. In Germany (which has stricter name laws than Austria and Switzerland), changing *ä,ö,ü,ß* to *ae,oe,ue,ss* in your name is easier than most other changes but still requires proof that the current spelling of your name presents a significant disadvantage to you.

Comment: @Taxxi You have to know whether it is supposed to represent an umlaut or not, consider for instance "Statue", "anaerob" or "Aloe Vera".

Comment: @maasumi and hansadler good points. I think generally one can say that replacing ü with ue is always acceptable. But you cannot just replace ue with ü unless you know what you are doing

Comment: Such transliterations are only acceptable in an environment that does not provide the original umlauts, and those are getting rare today (typewriters come to mind, or perhaps machine-readable passports). Everybody else should use the real thing, and it's really not hard in these days of ubiquitous Unicode support."But my keyboard is QWERTY" really doesn't cut it.

Comment: @ingmar while it is true that every system supports umlaute, it is a lot more complicated if you write more than just a few words. If I am writing on an english keyboard and it is not an official document I will always use ue instead of ü

Comment: Ok guys, I'm not talking about chaning every u into ü. Usual German nouns are all with the prescribed umlauts and finding umlaut characters is not a problem unless the internet connection is unavailabe, so there is really no reason to attach 'e' in most cases IMO. My question was about pronouns. Hans Adler's comment implies 'Nöther' is more preferable, which is different from Alexander's opinion. I recommend @HansAdler to post it as a separate answer if that seems plausible, because your opinion was the same impression I got when I've seen 'Noether'.

Comment: Or Alexander might want to add your personal opinion is also that 'Nöther' is more preferable(I'm not sure but I just guessed it from your comment above). This is for other people to use this information when they have to decide how they should write the name.

Comment: I don't know Noether but from your quote it sounds that she wrote her name with oe. Based in that, you should not write the name with ö, even if it is the same sound. Nevertheless there might be another person who's name is Nöther. If you refer to that person you should do it with ö. Similarly to Goethe who you would never spell with an ö, but today people might have last name that is spelled Göthe

Comment: @Taxxi "implies 'Nöther' is more preferable" -- general preference or official rules carry no weight when it comes to personal names or proper nouns. If a company makes up a word or alters an existing one for a product, that word does not have to submit to official spelling rules and is illegible for transliterations. This is the most liberal case. When we're talking about personal names, the spelling rules do not matter either, and transliteration rules for umlauts are not applicable. (cont'd)

Comment: Nowadays (in Germany), the spelling from the birth certificate is the only thing that matters regarding the spelling of a name. If there's a typo on the certificate, that typo basically becomes part of the only correct spelling of that name. It can be corrected through a bureaucratic process in which the name bearer has to show he's suffering from his current name or spelling (e.g. when named Adolf Hitler) and has to convince the relevant agency that no harm is done to society if the change is approved (i.e. he owes nobody money and is not a fugitive). (cont'd)

Comment: As for historical figures, I believe the variants that person used are the only valid ones. Usually one or two variants are dominating history books after some time, so using another variant impedes recognizability, even if said figure used to use the variant aswell.

Comment: So in essence, full ack from me to Alexander's last comment.

Comment: Added a section about this to make it clearer

Comment: Good, I see many people agree that case-by-case is the answer. I just wanted to make it clear since the comments seemed to imply the other way.

Comment: @Taxxi Haha... if there was Alö Vera in my hand lotion, I'd hesitate using it.

Answer (score 15):

**Proper nouns are not covered by orthographic rules, full stop.** That is *the* essence when asking for why a given person or a given place is spelt the way they are.

---

**Excursion on the use of umlauts**

For normal words, the general rule is to have *ü* for most /y/* sounds, *ö* for most /ø/ sounds and *ä* for a certain portion of the /ɛ/ sound. Neither of these rules is entirely strict, as /y/ can also be represented by *y* (*Zylinder*) and *ö* can also be represented by *eu* (*Chaffeur*) in words of foreign origin. The spelling of most words is fixed, i.e. **Zülinder* is as wrong as **Blyte* and **Chaufför* (or **Schofför*) is as wrong as **Geheur* would be. (The former works better, because *y* can only be /ü/ or /i/ whereas *eu* is usually /oi/.) There are a few exceptions such as *Friseur/Frisör* in which two spelling variants are possible, but only for very common loanwords.

It is debated but possible that the umlauts derived from some shorthand form of *e* above a preceding vowel — in the Middle ages there was a plethora of these shorthands around, all of them unregulated, and since the Latin alphabet in itself does not provide adequate lettering for Germanic languages, it was a logical choice to make. Therefore, at one point it became acceptable to replace umlauts with the corresponding letter plus *e.* The pre-1901 German spelling rules actively enforced that partially by not allowing capital umlauts: It had to be *Aepfel* and *Oel* — a phenomenon still visible in proper nouns such as the town of *Uelzen.* The reasoning was maybe that umlauted capital blackletters looked less appealing. This was changed, however. Whenever possible, one should write the correct umlauts, capitalised or lowercase, and only if technical restrictions do not allow so is one allowed to resort to *letter + e.* (The only truely valid context I can think of is naming variables in programming languages that restrict names to ASCII characters — so `aepfelzahl` would be acceptable there.)

---

**Back to proper nouns**

But the question was about proper nouns. Assuming a person could write, *nobody* could tell them how to properly spell their name. Not even the emperor tried to do that when accepting the 1901 spelling reform and the uproar would have been enourmous had they tried it in 1996. And remember that pre-1876, there were *no official spelling rules at all.* So people generally wrote freely — it has been mentioned that the well-known German poet and playwright spelt himself *Goethe, Göte* and *Göthe* on different occasions. Therefore, a lot of different spelling variants of identically pronunced names turned up, once literacy increased in the population. (And probably even before that, think christening lists in churches.) When finally people accepted a standard orthography for common nouns, there was a desire to also stick to the same way to write the corresponding common nouns. Since these were never regulated, many different variants still exist.

So in a nutshell, we write *Gödel* because Gödel’s ancestors used an *ö* in their name when it was fixed while we write *Noether* because Noether’s ancestors preferred *oe*. The surname *Schmidt* also exists as *Schmied, Schmitt, Schmid* and probably more although they all derive from *Schmied.* With *Meiers* it is even worse: each and every of the eight possible combinations is out there (*Mayr, Mair, Meyr, Meir, Mayer, Maier, Meyer, Meier*) sometimes in compounds sometimes not. *Müller* and *Mueller* are both common as is *Hoffmann* and *Hofmann*. I would imagine that apart from the reformator’s way of spelling (*Luther*) that *Lutter* and *Luter* should exist, too. You cannot even necessarily predict the pronunciation from the spelling: the novel of Thomas Mann is called *Buddenbrooks* although *Buddenbrocks* would have been a lot more logical in Lübeck, mainly because he didn’t want half the world to mispronunce their name (so urban legends say). A classmate of mine called *Kroiher* could have been spelt *Kreuer* by pronunciation, but a teacher once tried *Kroher* in analogy to [*Grevenbroich*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grevenbroich). And let us not forget the towns of *Uelzen, Itzehoe* and Buchloe, pronunced with an *Ü*, long *o* and *o-e* (two syllables), respectively.

And before you lean back please show me a language with not entirely phonetical spelling (i.e. Finnish doesn’t count) where you can immediately spell a person just from hearing their last name. Mr Davis/Davies? Mrs Brown/Browne? Mr [Raymond Luxury Yacht](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tyQvjKqXA0Y)?

---

*: I use the IPA symbols in a *very* generic way here, just to symbolise the sounds *ä, ö* and *ü* can make. I am well aware of the phonemic distinction between long and short vowels in German.

Comment: I asked this question not because I think every person's name is strictly governed by a certain law, but because from my prior knowledge in German, I couldn't remember using 'oe' in any nouns. So it was natural for me to think the original name is Nöther but people just might have written Noether. And I don't know a language satisfying your condition..

Comment: @Taxxi If that was your reason for a downvote, I think you are downvoting too laxly. Downvotes on answers should be reserved for misleading or wrong answers. Afaict I gave no wrong information, merely misunderstood your motivation for asking the question. If you did not downvote the answer, please ignore.

Comment: Taxxi seems to read things into texts which are not there, anyway.

Comment: I downvoted your answer, not because you provided wrong information, but because my question was not about randomness of the naming itself. The first half was helpful, but the second half is just about how spelling could vary. If that was lax, edit you answer once so that my vote lock-up will go away. I actually considered it a lot though.

Comment: @CarstenS What do you mean? I was just mentioning that I do acknowledge the point that spelling can be arbitrary in person's name.

Comment: *from some shorthand form of e above a preceding vowel* – I am not exactly sure what you want to call debated. There are tons of examples for aͤ, oͤ, and uͤ in typesetting up to the 19th century, and there are cases where one book switches between, say, *Goͤdel* and *Gödel* depending on the typeface. So it’s pretty clear that the two forms were synonymous.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I was mainly playing at people who say ‘two lines above a vowel look exactly like a *Sütterlin-* or *Kurrent-e*.’ Those were ‘invented’ much later than the umlauts to the best of my knowledge. I agree that both forms existed in parallel for an extensive amount of time. I don’t know if historians have concluded one form to be older than the other.

Comment: Regarding the assertion that "Assuming a person could write, nobody could tell them how to properly spell their name," my family was (so I'm told) apparently required by the German state to change the spelling of their name to a more historically accurate one, and this explains why my family (immigrated to the US ca 1914) spell the name one way while our cousins (who immigrated earlier) spell it differently.

Comment: That's the family lore, anyway. But it's events that happened 100 years ago, so maybe it's *Quatsch*.

Comment: And don't forget the [_Westfälisches Dehnungs-e_](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehnungszeichen#Dehnungs-e_nach_anderen_Vokalen) in places' names like _Soest_, _Coesfeld_, etc. where the _e_ is silent and makes the _o_ a long vowel, not an umlaut.

Comment: I back this answer with my name. It is and always has been spelled on all official German documents, including passports, ID cards and driver's licenses, as:

Comment: @yunzen Well, covered by *Itzehoe* although that's nowhere near Westphalia.

Answer (score 8):

A even more famous example is Goethe: The grandfather of the famous German poet

> Johann Wolfgang von G**oe**the

did not have the Name *Goethe*. His name was

> Friedrich Georg G**ö**the

(with **ö** instead of **oe**).

It would be wrong to write the poets name as *Göthe*, because this is not his name.

Friedrich Georg G**ö**the decided to change the writing of his name, and so his son (and his sons son) inherited the new name G**oe**the.

So when ever possible, you should write the name of the poets Grandfather F. G. Göthe, the name of the Austrian mathematician K. Gödel and my name H. Schölnast with **ö**. Only when the umlaut causes technical problems, you are allowed to replace the Umlaut (which is a relatively modern element of language) with its old and primordial version.

So, when you want to encode those names in 7bit-ASCII code, you should not only eliminate the dots (*Gothe, Godel* and *Scholnast* are definitely wrong!), but you should replace the dots by an e following the original vowel, which makes *Goethe, Goedel* and *Schoelnast*, and this is why the domain-part of my email-adress is not *schölnast.at* and not *scholnast.at* but *schoelnast.at*. (When I registered my domain in 2001 there was no way to use umlauts in domain names. Now it is possible.)

So, under special conditions (which are in most cases of technical nature), ö -> oe is allowed. But the other way (oe -> ö) is not. This is never ok. So it is an error to write the name of the poet J. W. Goethe with ö, and it is an error to write the name of Emmy Noether with ö.