# Warum ersetzt man in manchen Fällen »ä« durch »ae«?

Tags: spelling, umlaut, proper-noun

Laut meinem Assimil-Lehrbuch soll die Ersetzung von *ä* durch die Kombination *ae* stattgefunden haben, weil die früheren Schreibmaschinen  nicht über den Buchstaben *ä* verfügten.
Diese Erklärung scheint mir sehr bedenklich, insbesondere, weil Eigennamen  (zum Beispiel *Raeder*, das Beispiel im Assimil) vermutlich die Kombination *ae* schon enthielten, bevor Schreibmaschinen erfunden wurden.
Stimmt es also, dass die Erfindung der Schreibmaschine  die Ursache für die Ersetzung war? (Natürlich gilt die Frage auch für *ö, ü* usw.)

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26246/g%c3%b6del-but-noether

Comment: Es ist eine Tatsache, dass viele Schreibmaschinen keine Umlaute kannten und eine entsprechende Transliteration vorgenommen wurde.

Comment: Nein, damit hat sie nichts zu tun. Die Umlaute sind *ursprünglich* aus Kombinationen der Vokale mit einem hochgesetzten "e" (in Handschrift) entstanden. Daher ist es naheliegend, wenn man nicht mit einem "ä" auf der Tastatur gesegnet ist, auf die mittelalterliche Schreibweise zurückzugehen und "ae" zu schreiben - An sich wäre eigentlich 'a"' mMn auf einer Schreibmaschine viel naheliegender.

Comment: @tofro. Das wäre also die endgültige und klare Erklärung: vielen Dank. Kannst Du sie bitte in eine Antwort verwandeln, so dass ich sie annehmen kann?

Comment: An sich wird das Thema hier http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24000/evolution-of-the-digraph-ae-in-the-german-language-during-the-centuries?lq=1 wunderschön illustriert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nein, die Schreibmaschine und darauf fehlende Zeichen können nicht für Ortsnamen wie Moers oder Uelzen und Nachnahmen wie Schaetzer, Moeller oder Ruehle veranwortlich gemacht werden. Diese wurden allesamt verschriftlicht (aber nicht fixiert!), bevor an eine Schreibmaschine gedacht wurde.

Historisch gesehen sind die Umlaute aus nachgestellten *e*s entstanden; ob der Doppelpunkt wirklich aus dem Doppelstrich und dieser wiederum aus einem handschriftlichen *e* entstanden ist, ist [zweifelhaft](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/24018/15318). Beide Formen wurden lange Zeit parallel verwendet, wobei teilweise ein und derselbe Schreiber im gleichen Dokument beide Varianten für das gleiche Wort verwendet hat. Damals gab es noch keine fixierte Rechtschreibung; das galt für Wörter, Orte und Personen.

Mit der Zeit kristallisierten sich bevorzugte Schreibungen heraus. Der eine Möller hat sich lieber mit *ö* geschrieben, der andere lieber mit *oe*. Umgekehrt wurden Moers und Uelzen<sup>[1]</sup> weiter mit nachgestelltem *e* geschrieben, während fast alle anderen Städte die Umlautschreibung angenommen haben.

Im späten 19. Jahrhundert wurden Rechtschreibregeln schließlich fixiert. Wahrscheinlich ungefähr zur gleichen Zeit wurden auch die Schreibungen von Namen und Orten fixiert und haben sich seither nicht mehr verändert. Dass *ä* aus *ae* entstanden ist, dürfte weiterhin bekannt gewesen sein, denn einige Orte und Personen wurden ja weiterhin so geschrieben.

Die erste verbürgte Schreibmaschine scheint auf das Jahr 1808 zu datieren und wurde in Italien gebaut. Die erste Schreibmaschine, die in größeren Stückzahlen hergestellt wurde, wurde im Jahr 1865 konstruiert. Wirklich verbreitet war sie wahrscheinlich sogar noch später. Das heißt, dass sie erst so richtig aufgekommen ist, als die Schreibweisen von Namen und Orten schon fixiert waren.

Wegen internationalisierter Schreibmaschinenmodelle ohne Umlaute war es nötig, auf die *e*-Schreibung auszuweichen, wenn der Umlaut nicht vorhanden war. Das führte zu einer gewissen Renaissance der *e*-Schreibung in Schreibmaschinentexten. Dieser führte allerdings mit hoher Wahrscheinlichkeit *nicht* zu weiteren Personen, die ihren Nachnamen mit *e* statt Umlaut schrieben, und mit Sicherheit nicht zu veränderten Ortsschreibungen. Bedeutender dürfte die Auswanderung von Deutschstämmigen in die Vereinigten Staaten sein, die dort ihre Nachnamen dem dortigen Alphabet anpassten.

---

[1] Uelzen ist tatsächlich ein Sonderfall, da noch lange Zeit Umlaute vorwiegend als Kleinbuchstaben verwendet wurden, und für Großbuchstaben der Buchstabe mit nachgestelltem *e* verwendet wurde.

Comment: Danke, Jan: das ist sehr interessant.

Answer (score 1):

Die Umlautschreibungen mit "Dopplelstrich" (heute oft Doppelpunkt) stammen ja tatsächlich aus den Kombinationen a/o/u-e, da das "e" in der Currentschrift ja als zwei parallele Striche mit leichter Verbindung geschrieben werden.

Comment: Ich stehe dieser Erklärung sehr skeptisch gegenüber: Der Doppelstrich/Doppelpunkt ist anscheinend älter als das Doppelstrich-e der Kurrentschrift (mehr siehe [hier](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/24018/2594)). Kannst Du das irgendwie stichhaltig belegen?