〈ü〉 vs 〈ue〉 in German, particularly names
Default discussion on the internet seems to be that these two are entirely interchangeable. Just checking whether that's actually true, particularly in the case of names. It certainly seems, e.g., that the Jesuit explorer of Tibet Johann Grueber always gets his name spelled that way* even in sources where everything else is covered in umlauts and his companion has a dozen possible variations of Albert, comte d'Orville, exhaustively provided in French and translation.
Is that random and Grüber is actually perfectly fine but somewhat harder to type? Is this a thing where everyone aims to respect personal wishes? Can all ❬Ü❭s always be written as ❬UE❭, but not vice versa? Are there just usual versions for certain given and family names? Does it make some difference which era the name came from? or if one is following more recent orthographic reforms?
In short, what gives?
 
* ...aside from here where they're obviously just wrong/careless, possibly mixing him up with the SNL character.

Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/26246/3237

This question is similar to: Gödel but Noether?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have retracted my close vote since the question in the end isn't about umlaut.

No one really cares. It's better that you just delete the previous comment now that you realize it was mistaken. You can just add the link to Gödel but Noether? in a new comment without the extraneous bit.

ü and ue are not 100% equivalent.
In a computer context where it is difficult to produce "ü" (key missing, combination unknown) it is totally acceptable to replace an "ü" with "ue" in every text because often the Umlaut is still not supported by the underlying system or cannot be entered easily (as the key is missing in your keyboard layout).
In print media this is usually not done unless technical issues make it necessary.
On the other side replacing a "native ue" by an ü is not allowed. Most of the times this is for names.
That makes things complicated: if you find a "Thomas Mueller" in any written text you will never know, if the right way to write this name is "Thomas Müller" or "Thomas Mueller".

Normally it is totally acceptable to replace an "ü" with "ue". Do you have a source for that? Unicode is over 30 years old, I don't get why anybody would consider  for <ü> acceptable.

I work in IT since almost 30 years and I can asure you, that there are still multiple systems out there that are not capable of UNICODE. But to answer your question: No, I do not have a source for that except my own experience in this field but I for sure could find examples if I searched for them. But on passports e.g. in the machine readable part there still umlauts are replaced by the "ue" / "oe" or "ae" way to write them

The german passport e.g. still replaces the umlauts in its machine readable part as you can read here


I have encountered the kind of system you mention, but would not consider that their existence makes the practice of substituting umlauts acceptable; rather it seems to me that these systems should be considered deficient. 2. With regard to the passport example: Why would it follow from a narrow technical standard regarding machine-readable travel documents that this kind of substitution is acceptable in general?


You are right, probably my technical job makes me come to the wrong conclusions here.

Normally it is totally acceptable to replace an "ü" with "ue" in every text – That's wrong, and I think you should edit your answer accordingly. For example, only an extremely shoddy newspaper or book editor would consider that acceptable. The word "Brücke" is NOT spelled "Bruecke". The latter would simply be wrong in most texts.

In German crossword puzzles it's also very common practice to spell the umlauts as bigraphs. So it's not just an unheard of technical niche.

I would suggest repharsing the first sentence: IF, for some reason, you cannnot use umlauts, it is correct (and required) to replace ü-> ue etc. (and ß->ss). It would be wrong to write Müller as Muller.

@DavidVogt - While unicode is certainly a couple decades old, I'd be hard pressed to find a single user I know that can quickly, or efficiently, type the "ü" without Googling or taking a few minutes.  That's why I suspect "ue" still remains a popular alternative.

Is the case with ö & oe completely analogous?

I knew a Professor Boehm who would get quite grumpy if someone tried to spell his name “Böhm”. And I don't think I've ever seen Joseph Goebbels spelled “Göbbels”; For example German Wikipedia spells it with ‘oe’.

I changed my answer to show, that it refers to technical / computer texts more than to printed texts

Option-u u. For ë type option-u e. On an iPhone you hold the u key pressed until a row of alternatives appear. I surely hope that windows and Linux have caught up with that.

In short: No. Umlauts and their vocal transcriptions arent exactly identical (just have a look at the German word "Quelle" and it's obvious).
Names are always names. And the holder decides how he wants them spelt (within official rules). Changing other peoples' names can be considered rude, especially if there is no obvious reason (like a lack of a German keyboard) for it.
I, for example, am working with a large international company whose IT systems have problems with German Umlauts (a bit of a shame that shouldn't happen in 2024...), so I have to accept they write my name transcripted. But they sent a letter of apology when they started doing that ;)
With regards to last names, let's have a look at a somewhat more prominent example, Johann Wolfgang von Goethe, the famous German poet.
His Grandfather originated from Thuringa to Frankfurt as a tailor and held the family name of Göthe. When he acquired civil rights (and also some considerable wealth) in Frankfurt, he changed the writing to Goethe, apparently because he considered that more aristocratic. (And the name has stuck to all his descendants. Interestingly, when travelling, Goethe used the incognito name Johann Möller (with an Umlaut :) ). to hide his identity, so, there are signs that Umlauts in your name were considered more "middle-class")
As an anectote, decades ago, I used to have a teacher named "Kaeser" - He was apparently annoyed by pupils connecting his last name with "Käse" (which can be understood as "boring blurb", so insosted his last name was pronounced Ka - eser.
With regards to orthographic reforms: they have never affected the spelling of proper names.

The example of Goethe is a bit problematic. Before the introduction of state family registers and accompanying precise buerocratic rules, names were recorded by priests for the parish registers. And those, especially before the 19th century, took quite some liberties in writing down names according to their own understanding. (From my own family name, I know of a total of eight! different spellings between 1650 and 1850.) So unless there is concrete evidence that the Göthe/Goethe spelling is based on his own choice, I would be sceptical of interpretations.

@ccprog There is evidence. Göte's name change documents to the Frankfurt citizenship are preserved, apparently.

Göthe, the famous German pöt. (SCNR)

@AlexanderKlauer Göthe, the famous German poët. English is just extremely lazy about using clarifying diareses.

@AlexanderKlauer You seem to be missing an "a" in your nickname, surname part...

To understand German umlauts better, it might help to know where they came from:
When German nouns are declined (Hut → Hüte) or when verbs or adjectives are inflected (fallen → fällt; groß → größer) the Laut (sound) of a vowel gets changed in many words, so in English you might call that process to re-sound, and the German verb for that is umlauten. The noun Umlaut is what you get after that process, so an umlaut is literally a changed sound (of a vowel) that you maybe might call a re-sound in English.
Speaking is one thing, writing is another. The sounds, that this re-sound process created, are different from the sounds of other vowels, but the latin alphabet did not provide any letters to write those additional sounds. The reason for changing the sound of a spoken vowel in an declined or inflected word was in most cases an additional syllable at the end of the modified version with a bright sound (usually i or e) that influenced the vowel of the syllable before. And to indicate this in the written version of a word, people decided to add a copy of the letter e, taken form the following syllable, behind the vowel that becomes changed.
And so, these forms are the original written forms of German umlauts:

ae, oe, ue

But these letters have only this appearance when they are printed. But German handwriting (also known as Kurrent) used different glyphs. In this script the lowercase letter e looks like a mirrored N that has only the hight of a typical lowercase letter, and it has an additional strike at the beginning, which connects it to the preceding letter.
The point is now, that such modifications of already existing letters sometimes was not written behind the letter, but above it. In old German handwritings you also often can find a horizontal bar above some letter that normally would have to be written as double letter:

Pumpenkammer → Pumpenkam̄er (website with an image)

When you write that kurrent e above another letter, in handwriting this quickly is written as just two small slashes, and then it looks like this:

a̋, ő, ű

This is also the form I learned in school when I was learning handwriting in the early 1970s (I did not learn Kurrent), because tiny dashes are easier to see than just dots. But I also learned that in printed script, those dashes turn into dots, fat enough not to be overlooked.
The whole evolution from ae to ä can be seen in this image:

Source: Wikipedia
Translation:

... in a Latin handwriting
... in a German handwriting
... the e to the top and smaller
... simplification
... in a Latin handwriting again


What does this mean?
This means, that every »ä« is just a short form of »ae« and therefore every »ä« can be written as »ae« if writing of »ä« is hard (especially on non-German keyboards). (But »ä« is still the version to prefer!) (Same for the other umlauts.)
But the opposite is not true! If a word is written genuinely with »ae« (like Israel, Maestro, Michael, ...) these two letters must under no circumstances be replaced by »ä«! The reason is, that in these words »a« and »e« belong to two separate syllables and are pronounced separately. The »e« stands just by accident right behind the »a«. The »e« does not re-sound the previous »a«. (The same is true for words like Poesie, Oboe, aktuell, zuerst, ...)
A special case are names. They can contain »ae«, »oe« or »ue« even if these combinations are pronounced like umlauts (famous example: Goethe1). But the rule still holds here: Do never replace »ae«, »oe« or »ue« by »ä«, »ö« or »ü«. And for names with umlauts (like my own name: Schölnast) do the same that you do with all other words that contain umlauts: Write the umlaut when ever possible and use »ae«, »oe« or »ue« only in cases when its not possible to use umlauts. Omitting the dots without adding the »e« is always wrong!

1 I have written about Johann Wolfgang von Goethe and his grandfather Friedrich Georg Göthe and how the ö in this name turned into oe in an answer to another question.

every »ä« is just a short form of »ae«. This isn't true; Gäste comes from OHG gesti, Bär from bero, Mär from mâri. therefore every »ä« can be written as »ae«: Why would the genesis of <ä> from <aͤ> justify the substitution of <ä> by  in the present day?

Gäste comes from OHG gesti &c. at least seems entirely irrelevant. He's talking about the sound expressed by the modern ä, not the certain or presumed equivalent in OHG. For why would the genesis of ❬ä❭ from ❬aͤ❭ justify the substitution of ❬ä❭ by ❬ae❭ in the present day? at least seems similarly specious. It's the clear preference of most German writers, so you'd need to take that up with them and/or Googling, not present it as a personal challenge. Also pretty odd that you can type aͤ but not the correct angle brackets. Is it specially configured as a hotkey on your system?

One aspect that has not been mentioned is that <ue> can stand for /uː/. Digitales Familiennamenwörterbuch Deutschlands (DFD) states with regard to the name Hueber:

Benennung nach Beruf, siehe Huber 1. Es liegt eine Lautvariante mit erhaltenem Diphthong vor, die der Aussprache im bairisch-österreichischen Dialektraum entspricht. Durch den Einfluss der Schriftsprache wurde die Schreibung mit ue seit der zweiten Hälfte des 18. Jahrhunderts jedoch zunehmend durch die mit einfachem u ersetzt, die heute überall die wesentlich häufigere ist (siehe Hohensinner 2011, Seite 57). Weiter westlich kann Hueber auch eine Schreibvariante für Hüber 1 sein.

The same goes for Grueber. Note that in both cases, <ue> can also stand for /yː/.
The historical basis for <ue> for /uː/ is a process known as Early New High German monophthongisation: Middle High German <uo> /uə/ (later also <ue>) became New High German <u> /uː/; so Hufe, Hube derives from huobe and Grube from gruobe. As DFD says, Upper German dialects have conserved the older pronunciation: Huber, Gruber have a diphthong /uə/.
As the German Wikipedia states (unfortunately without giving a source), <ue> in Johann Grueber's name is /uː/ (Standard German) or /uə/ (in Upper German dialect).

I'd guess it is worth mentioning that the resulting monophthong is a long vowel (without context I'd interpret /u/ as short). (+1 anyway)

The short phonemes are usually different in quality, e.g. /ʊ/, therefore marking length is mostly redundant.

"Bauer" (literally "Farmer") is quite a common name in German. If you changed that to Baür that would be quite awful. There are quite a few cases where a, o, or u are followed by e. For example schlau = clever, schlauer = more clever, schlaür = really stupid.

It's not stated but I assume it would be 'quite awful' because the -er is an agentive suffix like English -er and Baür would be entirely mistaken, not merely personally unpleasant. (?)

@lly Yes a "bauer" is a Bau-er where "Bau" is a building hence a bauer is someone who builds. Though in that case it's more of a "(An-)Bau-er" so someone planting something aka a farmer. Using the "ü" would make it weird because that messes with the syllabils and how they start and end. Though given the different dialects I wouldn't rule out that there are people who's pronunciation comes closer to baür, though they rarely use the written form.
